# Visual Studio 2015 references

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sdk

I installed the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) https://developer.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk for Windows 8.1 but the problem persists

[image]

there a way to download these two references?

Error SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs, version = 12.0" was not found.
and Error SDK "SQLite.WinRT81, Version=3.14.2" was not found

Comment: what error do you get? check if the version is correct

Comment: Error SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs, version = 12.0" was not found.

Comment: and
Error SDK "SQLite.WinRT81, Version=3.14.2" was not found.

Comment: SQLite is written in C, it needs the CRT to get its job done.  Since you don't have SQLite, you wouldn't have its dependencies either.  Use the company's [download page](https://sqlite.org/download.html), you probably need the sqlite-winrt81-3150000.vsix package.